# Wordpress: add_submenu_page() creating error

Tags: wordpress, submenu

When I try to create a main menu, with this line

```
add_menu_page("page title","menu name",10,"test-slug");
```

Wordpress loads just fine and displays the new menu, but when I try to add a submenu,

```
add_menu_page("page title","menu name",10,"test-slug");
add_submenu_page("test-slug","sub title","sub menu",10,"test-sub-slug");
```

only an empty page is displayed, right after half a second. Seems like a php-error, but I can't see the error. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below in your functions.php file. It should work correctly.

```
add_menu_page(
    'Menu Page Title', // page title
    'Menu Menu Text', // menu link text
    'manage_options', // capability to access the page
    'menu_slug', // page URL slug
    'menu_callback_function', // callback function to display the content on options page
    'dashicons-format-status', // menu icon
    2 // priority
);

add_submenu_page(
    'menu_slug', // page URL slug
    'Sub Menu Title', // page title
    'Sub Menu Text', // menu link text
    'manage_options', // capability to access the page
    'submenu_slug', // page URL slug
    'submenu_callback_function', // callback function to display the content on options page
    1 // priority
);

function menu_callback_function(){
    echo "This is menu page...";
}

function submenu_callback_function(){
    echo "This is submenu page...";
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe point out what he did wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, it does not work. Wordpress displays an error message saying that there is a critical error on my website. Even when I only copy and paste the add_menu_page() example, the error is displayed. My own add_menu_page() example also doesn't work in functions.php. I have testet the functions.php with "echo 'test';" which works.

Comment: I'm afraid it is important to mention that I'm trying to write a simple plugin. The plugin does work thus far, but I'd like to add an options-page to the backend, accessable by a submenu item from an existing main menu item (so it won't clutter up the main menu by adding just one simple menu item). So I have tried add_submenu_page() and got stuck there. If adding submenus won't work on my Wordpress installation I'll keep the main menu entry.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. add_submenu_page() obviously must be called using a hook. Hence, this way it works and will not cause Wordpress to crash:

```
function dp_menu_item()
{
    add_menu_page("page title","menu name","manage_options","mypage.php");
    add_submenu_page("edit.php?post_type=cpt_people","sub title","sub menu","manage_options","mysubpage.php");
}
add_action("admin_menu", "dp_menu_item");
```